# convert java object to json with different object name

Tags: java, json

I want to convert java object to JSON with different object name.
For Example :

```
public class MetaProfileResponse {

    private Boolean tour ;

    private Integer maxFreeUser;

    private Boolean paid;

    private Integer status;
}
```

other Class is :

```
public class ProfileResponse {

    private String domainName;

    private String companyName;

    private String country;

    private String postCode;
}
```

A class have object of both class :

```
public class GetProfileResponse {

    private MetaProfileResponse metaProfileResponse;

    private ProfileResponse profileResponse;
}
```

when we get response as JSON We got :

{"metaProfileResponse":{"tour":null,"maxFreeUser":25,"paid":false,"status":0},"profileResponse":{"domainName":null,"companyName":null,"country":null,"postCode":null}}

But We want result as :
{"meta":{"tour":null,"maxFreeUser":25,"paid":false,"status":0},"profile":{"domainName":null,"companyName":null,"country":null,"postCode":null}}

without changing class name

Comment: Where you're using this objects? In REST?

Comment: Yes we are using in spring restful services

Comment: Try by using @XmlRootElement(name="meta") annotation in MetaProfileResponse

Comment: using that annotation we are getting same response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the annotation `@JsonProperty(value="whateverValueYouWant")` on the getter of `metaProfileResponse;`
It should give you proper result.

Comment: For this you need jackson core and jackson mapper jars

Comment: Which ways do I have to do this, if I am using objects from third party lib?